# intellij scala built-in formatter messing up partial functions

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, formatting

i'm trying to convince the built-in intellij scala formatter to format a partial function *as a parameter* like this:

```
PersistenceQuery(context.system)
  .readJournalFor[ScalaDslMongoReadJournal](MongoReadJournal.Identifier)
  .eventsByPersistenceId(persistenceId, 0, Long.MaxValue)
  .map(_.event)
  .collect[Thing]({
    case e:Foo => e // note the indentation
  })                // aligned with the .
  .runWith(Sink.asPublisher(fanout = false))
```

but, the best i can get is:

```
PersistenceQuery(context.system)
  .readJournalFor[ScalaDslMongoReadJournal](MongoReadJournal.Identifier)
  .eventsByPersistenceId(persistenceId, 0, Long.MaxValue)
  .map(_.event)
  .collect[Thing]({
  case e:Foo => e // unindented
})                // *under* indented!
  .runWith(Sink.asPublisher(fanout = false))
```

i'd prefer to use the built-in formatter over an external one.

anybody know what the right configuration incantation looks like?

intellij      2017.2.1
scala plugin  2017.2.13